# ExceptionInitializerError when setting system property before starting Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am facing an `ExceptionInitializerError` for a basic Spring Application when I attempt to set a system property before doing `SpringApplication.run`. If I *don't* set the system property, the Spring Application is able to start up fine.

Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ========================================
    // If I include this block, the application fails to start
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("testProperty", "5");
    System.setProperties(props);
    // ========================================
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Error:

```
10:56:51.753 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.AnsiOutputApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(AnsiOutputApplicationListener.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.AnsiOutputApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(AnsiOutputApplicationListener.java:37)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.demo.test.Application.main(Application.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)" because the return value of "java.lang.System.getProperty(String)" is null
    at org.springframework.boot.ansi.AnsiOutput.<clinit>(AnsiOutput.java:40)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the method *System.setProperty(String key,String valule)* instead of *System.setProperties*.
Using System.setProperties will overwrite the default system properties.

```
System.setProperty("testProperty", "5")
```

Comment: I don't mind it overwriting default system properties, I intend to load this Properties object from elsewhere and would use the `System.setProperties` method to load properties into my application.

Comment: It needs to read the system default properties when the Spring application starts. Using System.setProperties will remove them.